# Unable to deploy code from vs code to developer salesforce account

Tags: visualstudiocode

I have tried to deploy code from vs code to developer salesforce org but got this error in output.
c:\Users\Abhishek Kumar\Desktop\WebComponent\HelloWorldLightningWebComponent\force-app\main\default --json --loglevel fatal

After using the following command in terminal

> sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath c:\Users\Abhishek
>   Kumar\Desktop\WebComponent\HelloWorldLightningWebComponent\force-app\main\default
>   --json --loglevel

It gives the following error

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "name": "Error",
    "message": "Unexpected argument: Kumar\\Desktop\\WebComponent\\HelloWorldLightningWebComponent\\force-app\\main\\default\nSee more
    help with --help",
    "exitCode": 1,
    "commandName": "SourceDeployCommand",
    "stack": "Error: Unexpected argument: Kumar\\Desktop\\WebComponent\\HelloWorldLightningWebComponent\\force-app\\main\\default\n
    See more help with --help\n    at validateArgs
    (C:\\Users\\Abhishek Kumar\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.13.0-27dbcb37d3\\node_modules\\@oclif\\parser\\lib\\validate.js:10:19)\n  
    at Object.validate (C:\\Users\\Abhishek Kumar\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.13.0-27dbcb37d3\\node_modules\\@oclif\\parser\\lib\\
    validate.js:57:5)\n    at Object.parse (C:\\Users\\Abhishek Kumar\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.13.0-27dbcb37d3\\node_modules\\
    @oclif\\parser\\lib\\index.js:26:7)\n    at SourceDeployCommand.parse (C:\\Users\\Abhishek Kumar\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\
    7.13.0-27dbcb37d3\\node_modules\\@oclif\\command\\lib\\command.js:83:41)\n  
    at SourceDeployCommand.init (C:\\Users\\Abhishek Kumar\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.13.0-27dbcb37d3\\
    node_modules\\salesforce-alm\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\command\\lib\\sfdxCommand.js:203:44)\nOuter stack:\n   
    at Function.wrap (C:\\Users\\Abhishek Kumar\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.13.0-27dbcb37d3\\node_modules\\salesforce-alm
    \\node_modules\\@salesforce\\core\\lib\\sfdxError.js:151:27)\n    at SourceDeployCommand.catch (C:\\Users\\Abhishek Kumar
    \\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.13.0-27dbcb37d3\\node_modules\\salesforce-alm\\dist\\ToolbeltCommand.js:219:46)",
    "warnings": []
}
```

Comment: What specific command did you run? Please [edit] the body of your question.

Comment: Best you include the line that generates the error: looks like missing quotes so the space in the path "Abhishek Kumar" is being treated as a delimiter.

Comment: @KeithC I have mentioned the command in the body.

Comment: Hey @ASHUTOSHKUMAR, there is space on the file path, for windows I recommend you to wrap the entire path with double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

See [Syntax : Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html), so you need:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath "c:\Users\Anish Kumar\Desktop\WebComponent\HelloWorldLightningWebComponent\force-app\main\default" --json --loglevel
```

Comment: I have the issue in deploying my code from visualstudio to salesforce org.How it can be fixed.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try to move the code into a folder without spaces: something like c:\projects\WebComponent... ?

Comment: Ok Jeferson Chaves I am trying.

Comment: @Jeferson Chaves  I am able to create  the project name with demoLWC but not as mentioned in the trailhead  -'HelloWorldLightningWebComponent' project.